# Windows 10 BCDEdit - How to change {bootmgr} path?

Tags: windows, boot, windows-10, bcd

So basically, I'm trying to install rEFInd.  I've gotten everything to go successfully besides this part:

> Type bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi to set
>   rEFInd as the default EFI boot program. Note that {bootmgr} is entered
>   as such; that's not a notation for a variable. Also, change
>   refind_x64.efi to refind_ia32.efi on systems with 32-bit EFIs. Such
>   computers are rare, and most of them are tablets. Check your Windows
>   bit depth to determine which binary you should use.

I get this:
[image]

> The parameter is incorrect.

The exact line I enter is

> bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi

I recall this working in earlier versions of Windows, but not here.  What should I do?

Please note that EasyUEFI and VisualBCD are both screwing up.  Here is a full output of my current BCD:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a separate boot entry in NVRAM for rEFInd and set it as default (first boot choice) if this is the desired result. This should be possible using your UEFI firmware functionality for setting/creating new UEFI boot entry.

If this is not possible using firmware functionality:

I just changed "ApplicationPath" for {bootmgr} object using [Visual BCD Editor](http://www.boyans.net) in Windows 10 - 10240.

You have to map EFI System partition(ESP) to drive Z: for example (use diskpart.exe or mountvol.exe) and later use search button when editing ApplicationPath element to select rEFInd executable on ESP  -  "\EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi".
("ApplicationDevice" should show Z: or else you will get application exception)

[image]

Comment: I opened up Visual BCD, and selected Windows Boot Manager under Loaders.  From here, I tried double clicking ApplicationPath, entering the proper path, and clicking OK.  However, the value field did not update.  Using the search button and selecting the rEFInd .efi file that way didn't work either.

Comment: 1. Map ESP to Z:.  2. Select {bootmgr} and edit its ApplicationPath.

Comment: That's what I did.  I'll get you some screenshots, give me a second.

Comment: Before:  http://vgy.me/ZYh7J9.png

Comment: Right before hitting "OK":  http://vgy.me/A6s3e9.png

Comment: After:  http://vgy.me/7jiN01.png

Comment: DO NOT EDIT Windows Boot Manager BUT {bootmgr}.

Comment: Editing {bootmgr} gives the same issue:  Nothing happens after I click OK.

Comment: It looks like this both before and after editing:  http://vgy.me/nwbps1.png

Comment: 1. MOUNTVOL Z: /S (on admin command prompt) 2. OPEN VISUAL BCD EDITOR 3. Set {bootmgr} ApplicationDevice to Z:  4.EDIT "ApplicationPath". .....................SEE POSTED IMAGE.

Comment: Attempting to change the ApplicationDevice to Z: results in this error:  http://vgy.me/qYYJgM.png

Comment: Bcdedit /set {bootmgr} device partition=Z:

Comment: And? Is question solved?

Comment: Yes, I have marked it as solved and given reputation for your answer.  The key was setting the device partition.

Comment: Thanks for rep. Visual BCD Editor should be updated to fix "Unknown Device" as this only means that some utility has written nonsense in this BCD element (which is a true object/complex data structure).

Answer (score 18):

In Windows 10 you have to quote {bootmgr}. The new line is

```
bcdedit /set '{bootmgr}' path \EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi
```

Comment: Or use CMD instead of PowerShell.

Comment: @MartínColl You should post that as an answer, since that is THE answer.  Quotes will fail in cmd.exe but are needed in Powershell.

Comment: This did not work for me in WinRE with apostrophes (`'`), but worked using quotes (`"`).

Answer (score 2):

If you're using PowerShell you need to quote as answered by @zauguin.

Another option would be to use CMD, which is the terminal that the rEFInd author used when writing the guide.