# Windows keeps changing GPT table when it updates. How to prevent it?

Tags: multi-boot, windows-update, gpt

Running dual boot on a single disk with several partitions. Apparently a lot of times windows will modify the partition table in such a way that linux/grub stops  being the default. This happens once a month or so. Anyone has this problem and managed to solve it?

Comment: I doesn't change the partition table it changes the NVRAM.  You have to set it back with `bcdedit`.  See [Windows 10 BCDEdit - How to change {bootmgr} path?](https://superuser.com/questions/979695/windows-10-bcdedit-how-to-change-bootmgr-path)

Comment: This will stop it from re-happening?